# I use Catalina 10.15.7 and my terminal is /zsh. I had lot of “operation not permitted” or “permission denied” problems

Tags: macos, bash, zsh, sudo

I use Catalina 10.15.7 and my terminal is /zsh. I had lot of "operation not permitted" or "permission denied" problems. For example: [ sudo mv "/sbin/mount_ntfs" "/sbin/mount_ntfs.original" ] I wrote this and i have same problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

macOS introduced a security feature called System Integrity Protection which forbids changes to certain files and folders on the disk.  /sbin is among them.  It is possible to disable SIP via recovery mode but that is highly imprudent.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection

Comment: This is not a complete answer because as of Catalina, most of the OS is now in a read-only partition, and I'm pretty sure /sbin would be in that read-only partition. So in addition to disabling SIP, you'd need to remount the root partition read/write.

Comment: @Spiff Feel free to add to my response.  Recovery mode will still let you disable SIP and also mount the part as R/W